# The Definition of Hall effect

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter

I'm studying in Electricity course in my collage the [Hall effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect).
What is the Hall effect in simple way please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When electrons move in a magnetic field, the magnetic field [pushes them perpendicular relative to their motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) (sideways).  The same is true for current in a wire.  The electrons are moving in a magnetic field, and therefore the current is pushed to the side.  Since the negative charges are the ones that are free and moving, as they are pushed to the side, it leaves behind an excess of positive charge on the other side of the conducting wire.  This separation of positive and negative charges produces an electric field (and therefore a voltage) up to the point where it balances out the force from the magnetic field.  The voltage at this equilibrium is the Hall Voltage.